# Can we use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase for symfony 2 console commands testing?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

Using Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase, we get easy access to container, entity manager etc. We can use it for functional testing by automatic manual HTTP requests.

Can we use it to test Symfony2 console commands as well so that we can have easy access to container and all services?

I want to test my costum Symfony2 console commands which uses many services which in turn uses  doctrine entity manager to access data.

PHPunit documentation suggest to extend the test class with `PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase`,

Can we extend `WebTestCase` instead of test instead to test console commands ?

I have already refereed

- [How to test Doctrine Repositories <sup>*Cookbook*</sup>](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/doctrine.html)
- [How to test code that interacts with the Database <sup>*Cookbook*</sup>](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/database.html)
- [The Console Component <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WebTestCase` is meant for functional testing your web applications. Nothing will stop you from using it to test commands, but it doesn't feel right (hence your question).

**Testing commands**

Remember, that command tests (as well as controller tests) shouldn't be complex, just like the code you're putting in there shouldn't be complex either.

Treat your commands as controllers, make them slim and put your business logic where it belongs - to the model.

**Accessing the container**

Having said that, you can implement your own *KernelAwareTestCase* (or *ContainerAwareTestCase*) yourself. Here's a base class I'm using occasionally: [jakzal / KernelAwareTest.php <sup>*Gist*</sup>](https://gist.github.com/jakzal/1319290)

Also, note that next to `Symfony\Component\Console\Application` there's a `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application` which can actually work with the Symfony kernel.

**Final note**

Remember, that the most extensive testing should be done on a unit level.

Comment: Thanks, to access entity manager or doctrine entity repositories, what s the good practice, shall I use mock repositories or container aware test case ?

Comment: That depends on what kind of test you're writing. In unit tests you should mock your collaborators (avoid querying the database). In integration or functional tests, your could be accessing the database. You should write more unit tests than other kinds. Read on test pyramid (http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html, http://cuke4ninja.com/chp_three_layers.html).